# getting "Element should have been "select" but was "option" error while fetching data from the drop down

Tags: selenium, web, select, automation

I am trying to select an item from the select dropdown but facing an error

Html :

```html
<select _ngcontent-c8="" class="form-control">
  <option _ngcontent-c8="" value="" ng-reflect-value="">Select Priority</option>
  <option _ngcontent-c8="" value="HIGH" ng-reflect-value="HIGH">HIGH </option> 
  <option _ngcontent-c8="" value="MEDIUM" ng-reflect-value="MEDIUM">MEDIUM</option>
  <option _ngcontent-c8="" value="LOW" ng-reflect-value="LOW">LOW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelectors("select[class='form-control']"));

select.selectByVisibleText("HIGH");
```